# Add data from SQL in data grid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a function call `RetriveFile` in a class and I have a `DataGrid` in another form. I'm getting this error:

> invalid attempt to call rows when reader is closed.

Below is my code:

```vb
Public Shared Sub RetrieveFile(ByVal _paramSrc As String, ByVal Name As String)
    Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT Name, IsDeleted, Data  FROM tbldrive WHERE IsDeleted = '1' AND Name= '" + Name + "'"
    Try
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim sqldataSlt As SqlDataReader
        Dim SConn As String = ClsGlobalConnStr.GetConnString(_paramSrc)
        Using MyConnection As New SqlConnection(SConn)
            MyConnection.Open()

            Dim CmdSelect As New SqlCommand(strQuery, MyConnection)
            sqldataSlt = CmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
            table.Load(sqldataSlt)
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection

            If sqldataSlt.HasRows Then

                Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, MyConnection)
                    dad.Fill(Form1.table)

                    Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
                    sqldataSlt.Close()

                End Using

            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)


    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code makes little sense. You are executing the same query twice - once using a data reader and once using a data adapter - and populating two different `DataTables`. You also test the `HasRows` property of the data reader in between. If you were to explain what the code is actually supposed to do, we could probably explain how to do it. If the point is to populate a `DataTable`, pass that in as an argument and execute the query once. The form can bind its own grid.

Comment: hello.  I need to select data from a database . and populate these data in a datagrid

Comment: That last comment is uncalled for. We know you need help by the fact that you posed a question. Don't post garbage comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact cause of that error message but the code is so wrong that there's really no point in trying to work it out. Just write the code properly and the issue goes away.

That method should either look like this:

```vb
Public Shared Sub RetrieveFile(paramSrc As String, name As String, table As DataTable)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ClsGlobalConnStr.GetConnString(_paramSrc)),
          command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Name, IsDeleted, Data FROM tbldrive WHERE IsDeleted = 1 AND Name= @Name", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name

        connection.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            table.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

and be called like this:

```vb
RetrieveFile("...", "...", table)
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

or else look like this:

```vb
Public Shared Function RetrieveFile(paramSrc As String, name As String) As DataTable
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ClsGlobalConnStr.GetConnString(_paramSrc)),
          command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Name, IsDeleted, Data FROM tbldrive WHERE IsDeleted = 1 AND Name= @Name", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name

        connection.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim table As New DataTable

            table.Load(reader)

            Return table
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

and be called like this:

```vb
table = RetrieveFile("...", "...")
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Comment: thank you.. it work well but Data  from data field is not display in the grid. I think because its in binary format. is it possible to convert the binary format and display the correct format

Comment: Your question has already been answered. If you have a different question, start a new thread and post that question and all the information relevant to it. That said, make sure that you have done your own research first. This site is for the things you can't work out on your own, not the things you can't be bothered to work out.